PCs managed via InTune - Must bypass UAC prompt for silent uninstall
I manage a set of PCs via Microsoft InTune, and a pre-installed software (Firefox) must be uninstalled from those PCs due to company policy.
I found a way to perform a silent uninstall (Firefox doesn't show its uninstaller) with Firefox uninstall parameters (-ms or /S), but I'm still blocked by a Windows UAC prompt, asking permission to proceed with changes on the system. This happens even when I try the uninstall locally, as a local admin; and therefore, it can't work when triggered centrally via InTune.
Is there a way to bypass this UAC prompt so that the uninstallation is truly silent, allowing me to automate it via an InTune job?
Many thanks!

UAC applies to interactive sessions. Unattended activities performed by "Intune" and other Configuration Management solutions are not subject to UAC.

Thank you, I didn't know.
Is there a way to better capture what the error is, within InTune? Maybe I'm on the wrong track, and it's not the UAC warning that causes my issue?
I test "locally", I get this UAC prompt, and I suspect this is what causes the InTune error... But with what you explain to me, this must be something else...
Thanks!
